# Using same function on multiple datasets and using specific columns

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

I have 8 datasets and I want to apply a function to convert any number less than 5 to NA on 3 columns(var1,var2,var3) of each dataset. How can I write a function to do it effectively and faster ? I went through lots of such questions on Stack overflow but I didnt find any answer where specific columns were used. I have written the function to replace but cant figure out how to apply to all the datasets.

```
Input:
Data1
variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4
10           36        56        99
15           3         2         56
4            24        1         1

Expected output:
variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4
10           36         56        99
15           NA         NA        56
NA           24        NA         1
```

Perform the same thing for 7 more datasets.

Till now I have stored the needed variables and datasets in two different list.

```
var1=enquo(variable1)
var2=enquo(variable2)
var3=enquo(variable3)
Total=3


listofdfs=list()
listofdfs_1=list()
for(i in 1:8) {
  df=sym((paste0("Data",i)))
listofdfs[[i]]=df
  }

for(e in 1:Ttoal) {    
listofdfs[[e]]= eval(sym(paste0("var",e)))
}
```

The selected columns will go through this function:

```
temp_1=function(x,h) {
  h=enquo(h)
  for(e in 1:Total) {    
  if(substr(eval(sym(paste0("var",e))),1,3)=="var") {
 y= x %>% mutate_at(vars(!!h), ~ replace(., which(.<=5),NA))
 return(y)
  }

}
}
```

I was expecting something :

lapply(for each dataset's selected columns,temp_1)

Comment: @MrFlick   Sorry for the inconvenience ! I have edited the question.

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry for that I have edited !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach that should work:

```
cols_to_edit = paste0("var", 1:3)
result_list = lapply(list_of_dfs, function(x) {
  x[cols_to_edit][x[cols_to_edit] < 5] = NA
  return(x)
})
```

I assume your starting data is in a list called `list_of_dfs`, that the names of columns to edit are the same in all data frames, and that you can construct a character vector `cols_to_edit` with those names.

Comment: My variable names are same in all datasets but it can change in future hence I have tried to use like macro. The variable name in future can change form variable3 to variable4 hence I wanted to use macro. when i tried you code : cols_to_edit = eval(sym(paste0("var", 1:3)))
result = lapply(list_of_dfs, function(x) {
  x[cols_to_edit][x[cols_to_edit] < 5] = NA
  return(x)
}) it gives error: Error in `*tmp*`[cols_to_edit] : 
  object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

Comment: Yeah, so my code works but when you change it to `eval(sym())` it doesn't work. Why don't you just create string column names? Seems still modular, but much simpler. You can change `cols_to_edit = paste0("var", 1:3)` to `cols_to_edit = paste0("var", 1:4)` just as easily---except that the rest of the code works too.

Comment: But var1 can resembles variable1. I don’t want to hard code it. In future if var1 resembles some different name than it would be easy if it’s not hard coded. Hence I need to use eval

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to the problem in the question.
First of all, create a test data set.

```
createData <- function(Total = 3){
  numcols <- Total + 1
  set.seed(1234)
  for(i in 1:8){
    tmp <- replicate(numcols, sample(10, 20, TRUE))
    tmp <- as.data.frame(tmp)
    names(tmp) <- paste0("var", seq_len(numcols))
    assign(paste0("Data", i), tmp, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
}

createData()
```

Now, the data transformation.
This is much easier if the many dataframes are in a `"list"`.

```
df_list <- mget(ls(pattern = "^Data"))
```

I will present  solutions, a base R solution and a `tidyverse` one. Note that both solutions will use function `temp_1`, written in base R only.

```
library(tidyverse)

temp_1 <- function(x, h){
  f <- function(v){
    is.na(v) <- v <= 5
    v
  }
  x[h] <- lapply(x[h], f)
  x
}

h <- grep("var[123]", names(df_list[[1]]), value = TRUE)

df_list1 <- lapply(df_list, temp_1, h)
df_list2 <- df_list %>% map(temp_1, h)

identical(df_list1, df_list2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hello I am sorry but I forgot to mention I need to use vars as macro variables so that when I use eval it resolves to Variable1,Variable2 and Variable3. So can you help with that ? the variable h which stores the names wont work how you have mentioned in the code.